# https on error function not catching 503 error

Tags: node.js

the server is sending a 503 error but the res.on('error') function does not print it.

```
https.get(url, function(res){
            var body = '';

            res.on('data', function(chunk){
                body += chunk;
            });

            res.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

            res.on('end', function(){
               var response = JSON.parse(body);
               console.log(response.stream);

                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error status codes do not trigger `error` events as they are a higher level error. `error` events for an `http.request()`/`https.request()` would be things like abrupt socket disconnection, malformed response (e.g. bad chunked transfer encoding), etc.

You can simply check `res.statusCode` if you need to perform different logic in case of a 503 for example.